# Checking file after creating. FS + timeout?

Tags: node.js, express

After ajax request, I send options for Image Magick (child process) and create file.
If I send response to client immediately - I have error - img non exist. My solution, set Timeout and send response (hardcode). 
I can set timeout and check file with fs module, but it is right way? 
Or may be I can emit new event after file exist, but can you type sample for me? 
Or this task have another solution?

```
fs.stat(currentImage, function(err, background) {

        if (background && background.isFile) {

            async.series([
                function(callback) {
                    var magickOpts = memOptions;
                    var im = spawn('convert', magickOpts);
                    callback(null, 'done');
                }
            ],
            function(err, result) { 
                setTimeout(function() {
                    res.send({
                        status: '200',
                        src: '/images/mems/'+tempName+'.jpg',
                        tempName: tempName
                    }); 
                }, 500);
            });

        } else {
            res.send({
                status: '404',
                text: 'background image not found'
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: Hi, @robertklep. Code attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should wait for the child process to exit (by listening for the `close` event) before you send the response to the client.

Also, `async.series` doesn't seem to be really used in this case, so I left it out:

```
fs.stat(currentImage, function (err, background) {

  if (background && background.isFile) {
    var magickOpts = memOptions;
    var im = spawn('convert', magickOpts);
    im.on('close', function() { 
      res.send({
        status: '200',
        src: '/images/mems/' + tempName + '.jpg',
        tempName: tempName
      });
    });
  } else {
    res.send({
      status: '404',
      text: 'background image not found'
    });
  }

});
```

By the way, there's also the [`im`](https://npmjs.org/package/im) package which wraps ImageMagick for use in Node.

Comment: Wow! Thank you! I can listen 'close' from all other child process?)

Comment: @MaxP not sure what you mean, but the `close` event is the one to listen for if you want to know if a child process created by `spawn` has exited

Comment: yeap, it is. Tnank you very much, @robertklep